# Finding the closest point on an edge

Tags: geometry, plane-geometry

I am working on my Computer Graphics assignment and wanted to know if there was a more optimized way of determining the closest point along an edge to a given point. Here is how I am doing it currently:

I am doing a mouse press (green dot) and then doing a mouse release (blue dot). I want to find the closest point along the edge of the window to the blue dot.

I create four lines with each of the corners (each purple dot) `[[TopLeft, Bottom Left], [BottomLeft, BottomRight], ...]` and then do a [line-line intersection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93line_intersection) with the green dot to blue dot to each of the lines. From there I take the distance between the blue dot and the intersecting point from the line-line test, and selecting the smallest point.

[image]

I wanted to know if there was a better solution to finding this point. Maybe something like this? Where I can extend the line in either direction, find the two red dots, and select the one closest to the blue dot?

[image]

Comment: Matt can you mention names of points so that question is clear.

Comment: The question isn't very clear... isn't the closest point just the foot of the perpendicular from the point to the edge?

Comment: Sorry for any confusion. I am looking to find the coordinates of the point along an edge in the window. In this example it would be the `x, y` of the red dot on the bottom edge ( 2nd image ).

Answer (score 0):

I tried to simplify your problem to the following:

Given an edge, find the closest point on the closest edge to it.

1) Find the closest edge which intersects with yours, just run on all the possible edges and find with who you intersect, there could be several.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-if-two-given-line-segments-intersect/

2) Choose the closest edge to your point from the found set in phase 1.
Take the minimal value of the function, thats your needed edge.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30559799/function-for-finding-the-distance-between-a-point-and-an-edge-in-java?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

3) Once found which one you intersect with, a simple equation would return that number.
http://zonalandeducation.com/mmts/intersections/intersectionOfTwoLines1/intersectionOfTwoLines1.html

Hope this helps.